# Type-level Catalan function in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, catalan

Consider the following Catalan function in JavaScript.

```js
class Pair {
    constructor(fst, snd) {
        this.fst = fst;
        this.snd = snd;
    }
}

const catalan = (x, xs) => {
    if (xs.length === 0) return [x];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        const ys = catalan(x, xs.slice(0, i));
        const zs = catalan(xs[i], xs.slice(i + 1));
        for (const y of ys) for (const z of zs) result.push(new Pair(y, z));
    }
    return result;
};

const show = (x) => x instanceof Pair
    ? `(${show(x.fst)} <> ${show(x.snd)})`
    : JSON.stringify(x);

const log = (x) => console.log(x);

catalan(1, []).map(show).forEach(log);
catalan(1, [2]).map(show).forEach(log);
catalan(1, [2, 3]).map(show).forEach(log);
catalan(1, [2, 3, 4]).map(show).forEach(log);
```

It returns all the possible ways of associating `n` applications of a binary operator, where `n = xs.length`.

I want to do something similar, but with types in TypeScript. However, I don't know how to implement the “else” branch.

```js
class Pair<A, B> {
    constructor(public fst: A, public snd: B) {}
}

type Catalan<X, XS extends unknown[]> = XS extends []
    ? X
    : /* how to define this “else” branch? */;

type C0 = Catalan<1, []>; // 1

type C1 = Catalan<1, [2]>; // Pair<1, 2>

type C2 = Catalan<1, [2, 3]>; // Pair<1, Pair<2, 3>> | Pair<Pair<1, 2>, 3>

type C3 = Catalan<1, [2, 3, 4]>; /* Pair<1, Pair<2, Pair<3, 4>>> |
                                  * Pair<1, Pair<Pair<2, 3>, 4>> |
                                  * Pair<Pair<1, 2>, Pair<3, 4>> |
                                  * Pair<Pair<1, Pair<2, 3>>, 4> |
                                  * Pair<Pair<Pair<1, 2>, 3>, 4>
                                  * /
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. By the way, I want to use this `Catalan` type to define the following function.

```js
declare const flatten: <X, XS extends unknown[]>(
    x: Catalan<X, XS>
) => [X, ...XS];
```

Here's how the `flatten` function is implemented in JavaScript.

```js
class Pair {
    constructor(fst, snd) {
        this.fst = fst;
        this.snd = snd;
    }
}

const catalan = (x, xs) => {
    if (xs.length === 0) return [x];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        const ys = catalan(x, xs.slice(0, i));
        const zs = catalan(xs[i], xs.slice(i + 1));
        for (const y of ys) for (const z of zs) result.push(new Pair(y, z));
    }
    return result;
};

const flatten = (x) => x instanceof Pair
    ? [...flatten(x.fst), ...flatten(x.snd)]
    : [x];

const log = (x) => console.log(JSON.stringify(x));

catalan(1, []).map(flatten).forEach(log);
catalan(1, [2]).map(flatten).forEach(log);
catalan(1, [2, 3]).map(flatten).forEach(log);
catalan(1, [2, 3, 4]).map(flatten).forEach(log);
```

---

**Edit:** If it helps, here's an implementation of the value-level `catalan` function in Haskell.

```hs
import Data.List (inits, tails)

data Catalan a = Catalan a :<>: Catalan a | Lift a deriving Show

split :: [a] -> [([a], [a])]
split = init . (zipWith (,) <$> inits <*> tails)

catalan :: a -> [a] -> [Catalan a]
catalan x [] = [Lift x]
catalan x xs = do
    (ys, z:zs) <- split xs
    y <- catalan x ys
    z <- catalan z zs
    return $ y :<>: z

main :: IO ()
main = do
    mapM_ print $ catalan 1 []
    mapM_ print $ catalan 1 [2]
    mapM_ print $ catalan 1 [2, 3]
    mapM_ print $ catalan 1 [2, 3, 4]
```

Here's the output of the above Haskell program.

```hs
Lift 1
Lift 1 :<>: Lift 2
Lift 1 :<>: (Lift 2 :<>: Lift 3)
(Lift 1 :<>: Lift 2) :<>: Lift 3
Lift 1 :<>: (Lift 2 :<>: (Lift 3 :<>: Lift 4))
Lift 1 :<>: ((Lift 2 :<>: Lift 3) :<>: Lift 4)
(Lift 1 :<>: Lift 2) :<>: (Lift 3 :<>: Lift 4)
(Lift 1 :<>: (Lift 2 :<>: Lift 3)) :<>: Lift 4
((Lift 1 :<>: Lift 2) :<>: Lift 3) :<>: Lift 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**updated may 19**

Oh boy, we aren't done yet. We can make this thing even faster!

The first thing you can do is transform the extends in `Catalan` to only:

```
type Catalan<X, XS extends List> = ({
    "0": X;
    "1": Pair<X, XS[0]>;
} & {
    [_: `${number}`]: CatalanLoop<X, XS>;
})[`${XS["length"]}`];
```

This makes it extremely fast. It's only a lookup table now.

Then instead of big clunky loop for `CatalanLoop`, we can use distributive conditional types!

```
type CatalanLoop<X, XS extends List, K extends keyof XS & `${bigint}` = keyof XS & `${bigint}`> =
        K extends K
            ? Partition<XS, K> extends infer P
                ? P extends [List, List]
                    ? P extends P
                        ? CatalanPairs<X, XS, P, K>
                        : never
                    : never
                : never
            : never
```

And you'll notice a new type to help with the distributing:

```
type CatalanPairs<X, XS extends List, P extends [List, List], K extends keyof XS> = K extends K ? Pair<Catalan<X, P[0]>, Catalan<XS[K], P[1]>> : never;
```

Try [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMglgZ2FAvFAShAhgEwPYB2ANiAIIBO5WIAPAK4EDWBeA7gQHwDcAUDwMZEsCBFAAKWOORqkANFABCHKAG8o-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-zgaCjpMwPB4MC9+sVim85tkyvV2t7gBkMvlJjgUMhwBVOKrNbrjMvcpUN7vMRV9K1dyPZlRFLf8TUlcQsDOC44CuJ55FLZQWzBIVsTEUCwLudt90LSli0pY0MMI7U8yQ0Q0KIiiTSlddxw7BBdzg8R4KDSjWKgRcI3IdDWI4rFuIw3iuJ4qBQ04ldAhoicM2eUjYEpRsDBUcUACIamU2x7l4OFlISdSIKkBjHgHIdeB8S8lLhOIAH1bA-NEMSxFU9lsSTN23QzuB4Lx3DiD9J2UohoihYAAAtlL2Jyo1XWMahxSSaAaGlPOjGMEji+MxytRLkhMo5opjZJ0u7ccEvkOIdlylK0iKzLSupHYskq-LMhqntsvSLJciaiSclakr2qgVp2k6fJcrywJHhCtgaDoxs6OwjsaBQux5GWpRwOlAx5Um6bSA4HwaGUbaptYGglG81VbPlebL3szFyBVKKJpOmNYrQHbTte5Loo+1KcQ+mhUu+562AK-6TsB5JgegX7qveiGYzSaGoF+lr4emmNMmR37evRz6cm4IA) new playground to see the effects of these changes.

---

When encountering type-level problems like these, it's best to look at the original code and look for patterns, or anything that the type system can do for you.

So let's begin:

```
const catalan = (x, xs) => {
    if (xs.length === 0) return [x];
    const result = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < xs.length; i++) {
        const ys = catalan(x, xs.slice(0, i));
        const zs = catalan(xs[i], xs.slice(i + 1));
        for (const y of ys) for (const z of zs) result.push(new Pair(y, z));
    }
    return result;
};
```

First we notice that if `xs` is empty, then we directly return `x`. We make a mental note to use `XS["length"] extends 0 ? X : ...` later.

Then we see that this:

```
const ys = catalan(x, xs.slice(0, i));
const zs = catalan(xs[i], xs.slice(i + 1));
```

is really just partitioning `xs` in such a way that:

```
partition [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] at 3 => [1, 2, 3] [5]
```

In other words, we split the tuple at index 3 and return the two halves. This will be much faster than slicing the tuple two times individually and can be implemented without much trouble.

Finally we notice this nested loop:

```
for (const y of ys) for (const z of zs) result.push(new Pair(y, z));
```

No need for this in the type system, we can simply do:

```
Pair<YS, ZS>
```

and have it generate all the possible pairs for us from the unions.

Alright, time to get cracking away at the solution.

Recall that `x` is returned if `xs` is empty:

```
type Catalan<X, XS extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = 
  XS["length"] extends 0 ? X :
```

And also when `XS` is only one element then we return that pair. If `XS` has more than one element, we enter the loop instead:

```
... : XS["length"] extends 1 ? Pair<X, XS[0]> : CatalanLoop<X, XS>;
```

Let's see the loop now:

```
type CatalanLoop<X, XS extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof XS & `${bigint}`]: ...
}[keyof XS & `${bigint}`];
```

Now, what's this funny looking thing:

```
keyof XS & `${bigint}`
```

`keyof XS` would give us something in the form of `number | "0" | "1" | "2" | "at" | "concat" | "..."`, but we only want the indices of `XS`. If we intersect `keyof XS` with the interpolated `bigint`, we get the desired `"0" | "1" | "2"` only.

That means this is just like the loop in the original code! We loop over each index using a mapped type.

Inside the loop body we partition `XS` at index `K`:

```
type CatalanLoop<X, XS extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>> = {
  [K in keyof XS & `${bigint}`]:
    Partition<XS, K> extends [infer Left, infer Right]
      ? ...
      : ...
}[keyof XS & `${bigint}`];
```

But we have to assert to TypeScript that our partitioning type will definitely give us tuples like this first:

```
    Partition<XS, K> extends [infer Left, infer Right]
      ? Left extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
        ? Right extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>
```

Then we call `Catalan` and make our pairs:

```
          ? Catalan<X, Left> extends infer YS
            ? Catalan<XS[K], Right> extends infer ZS 
              ? Pair<YS, ZS>
```

This is doing what this original code does:

```
const ys = catalan(x, xs.slice(0, i));
const zs = catalan(xs[i], xs.slice(i + 1));
for (const y of ys) for (const z of zs) result.push(new Pair(y, z));
```

And let's close off all our ternaries/conditionals with `never` (because these clauses should never be reached anyways):

```
              : never
            : never
          : never
        : never
      : never
```

Finally, we need to make our partitioning type.

To do that, we need a type to increment a number. This can be done with a tuple like this:

```
type Increment = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33];

Increment[0]  // => 1
Increment[15] // => 16
Increment[32] // => 33
```

Now that we can increment a number, we define `Partition`:

```
type Partition<
  XS extends ReadonlyArray<unknown>,
  At extends string,
  Index extends number = 0,
  Left extends ReadonlyArray<unknown> = [],
> = XS extends [infer First, ...infer Rest]
    ? `${Index}` extends At
      ? [Left, Rest]
      : Partition<Rest, At, Increment[Index], [...Left, First]>
    : never
```

This type loops over `XS` until it hits `At`, the index to partition at. It excludes the element at `At` and stops, giving us `[Left, Rest]`, the two halves. `Partition` is the type that replaces `xs.slice(0, i)` and `xs.slice(i + 1)`.

Lastly, just for kicks, let's also make a type to mimic the original `show` function:

```
type Show<Pairs> = Pairs extends Pair<infer A, infer B> ? `(${Show<A>} <> ${Show<B>})` : `${Pairs & number}`;
```

And wow! It really does work!

```
type ShowFifth = Show<Catalan<1, [2, 3, 4, 5]>>;
// =>
// | "(1 <> (2 <> (3 <> (4 <> 5))))"
// | "(1 <> (2 <> ((3 <> 4) <> 5)))"
// | "(1 <> ((2 <> 3) <> (4 <> 5)))"
// | "(1 <> ((2 <> (3 <> 4)) <> 5))"
// | "(1 <> (((2 <> 3) <> 4) <> 5))"
// | "((1 <> 2) <> (3 <> (4 <> 5)))"
// | "((1 <> 2) <> ((3 <> 4) <> 5))"
// | "((1 <> (2 <> 3)) <> (4 <> 5))"
// | "((1 <> (2 <> (3 <> 4))) <> 5)"
// | "((1 <> ((2 <> 3) <> 4)) <> 5)"
// | "(((1 <> 2) <> 3) <> (4 <> 5))"
// | "(((1 <> 2) <> (3 <> 4)) <> 5)"
// | "(((1 <> (2 <> 3)) <> 4) <> 5)"
// | "((((1 <> 2) <> 3) <> 4) <> 5)"
```

To end off this little adventure, [a playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKYEsBOAeAggGmgIQHzQG9pgB7AOwgBckBXYSkpACgAcaAjEBYaAMyoBc0TNDadu0CGQAmQ7AEpCAX2hKAUGsoBPFgFNoASTLAkugLa6ylaAF5oAbQCMWAExYAzFgAsWAKxYANiwAdiwADiwATixHAAYY52hHNyTPJJ8k-ySgpNCkiKTo6Bd44sSXFJc0lwyXLJcclzyXApci91L3RPcU93cAXQBuDW09ODAkSgQp8hQ1aGgADQBlaF0AD0pLaRgAJV0waXIQLTQkJDAtFBoyAGsyEgB3MlwMeeFrDa2ZGCokBDIAHM3gsjNINmtNtsYGQaGZ2LokLZoPF3gAZXS8T5Qn7QfaHY6nc6Xa53B7PfB2ez9N6UparL7QhwA3iI6AAMWQVCwADo+Sy2fsqP13gsAPzQAAGABICGCNkpJZDvjsPqKFtAJfYMVisELKCKNRqhPBJtMELN9Vg0JQsEYTOZLJR7PL1jSHHyeTrbRyuQbcOqhGRdAA3REjHT6ADCYEoYHAZDRJBILBQiywK2VTPxRzIJzOFyuN3uTxedII73sAGloADoLddFoSLx6dAAGRS2XsBCAgGURX9ATq01TGZkNPLLBV-CM3H2AVI71YBd4nsACwN6vF0G9WdxOcJBZJxfJLy3Golu3X2JVewOufzxKLZNLAaN7810BjcYTaaw3pnHFVRXABNZZzw-CVv3jMBxxWat3SvQEN0A29azIVkkQALVWCCP0-eBkBQMCsBwt98I-INQ3DCijSosMkDwhZ6Jo-CWMYyjoGDBi1CUewGybFtMw7GUCG7XsrAHYZNEjL9YxguCMwZIC7wJPMiULUkSwpOl3nggAiEBLEBSg130-o91VWJP0WaAhAMoygVM8zLJgRwCMQVB03pexYn6fAhGghMkxTP96VwaTRn0ZY1yeFBCKQCA6QSmBZ1VBKUBXEQVzwT9JSYWUYritBcBUFB8EK2LHhQPAlHkJUhFElL2y4uEESQRVItkqNrLsILYJQRJqQi6AAHpRqSCMxijdy+vk38hpcfzBjGiaMvKAMZOmlxkX68dFo8ZbVvGIjEgy3pcHwAAfE7UHW1xXmgdxNqir93F2+aBoOp7vD8I7RoAKluwasHO0HPJQNIvEu66mNo+HaKB+7gbBp7Huh2GEax7HoCRiHkZcR6Mqhy7oCuuGcexvGiOR1HnvRzHKaZ99qbu-GIY2jwGYp5nEdGqboqqnrkSK6qeoitRxo1AA9MUtsFp4ZpFqqUBmiWpYWWX5egUWox2uxRdVwnhg16Atde3X3oNlWo2ek2Js1uXtYAFV0KhZuBs6IZSYnvBh1y3s-agaH0IReHjCBdBdt3KH1z3wZp72ub91CmVtoPaFDvgI6j17XaoK2UY5h6E9QEnU9xdOJWDrPw5ASPo6oLxkQy2mk7RhmA6r6Aa7s7P69z2T88oXwW-ZxPTpLtG-a797q8zvu64boA) where you can play around with this yourself.

Answer (score 1):

So here is my attempt:

First of all, I am not sure if I understood the Catalan algorithm correctly. I created this type purely by looking at the examples you gave. You need to test if this works for bigger tuples as well.

### Explanation

I used some utilities to solve this problem. I needed a type to `splice` arrays, so I used the type `Splice` from [here](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/585).

```
type Absolute<T extends string | number | bigint> = T extends string
  ? T extends `-${infer R}`
    ? R
    : T
  : Absolute<`${T}`>;

type isNegative<T extends number> = `${T}` extends `-${infer _}` ? true : false;

type SliceLeft<
  Arr extends any[],
  Index extends number,
  Tail extends any[] = []
> = Tail["length"] extends Index
  ? [Tail, Arr]
  : Arr extends [infer Head, ...infer Rest]
  ? SliceLeft<Rest, Index, [...Tail, Head]>
  : [Tail, []];

type SliceRight<
  Arr extends any[],
  Index extends string,
  Tail extends any[] = []
> = `${Tail["length"]}` extends Index
  ? [Arr, Tail]
  : unknown extends Arr[0]
  ? [[], Tail]
  : Arr extends [...infer Rest, infer Last]
  ? SliceRight<Rest, Index, [Last, ...Tail]>
  : [[], Tail];

type SliceIndex<
  Arr extends any[],
  Index extends number
> = isNegative<Index> extends false
  ? SliceLeft<Arr, Index>
  : SliceRight<Arr, Absolute<Index>>;

type Slice<
  Arr extends any[],
  Start extends number = 0,
  End extends number = Arr["length"]
> = SliceIndex<SliceIndex<Arr, End>[0], SliceIndex<Arr, Start>[0]["length"]>[1];
```

I also needed a way to convert the indizes of the array produzed by `keyof X` (which are strings) back to numbers. I used this helper type:

```
type Indizes = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20]
```

Now to the algorithm itself.

It was not clear to me why `X` and `XS` needed to be seperate things. For the first step I took `X` and `XS` and merged them into a single array.

```
type Catalan<X, XS extends unknown[]> = _Catalan<[X, ...XS]>
```

To evaluate the result I created the recursive type `_Catalan` which takes a tuple. The first two steps are simple. If the tuple is of `length` 1, return the element inside the array. If it is of `length` 2 ,return a `Pair` of the first two elements.

```
X["length"] extends 1 
  ? X[0]
  : X["length"] extends 2 
    ? Pair<X[0], X[1]>
    : /* ... */
```

The rest is a bit more complicated. My approach was to "cut" the array once at every possible index and recursively call `_Catalan` with both resulting sub-arrays.

```
[ 1 , 2 , 3 , 4 ]

    |                <- first cut here

[ 1 ] [ 2 , 3 , 4 ]

          |          <- next cut here

[ 1 ] [ 2 ] [ 3 , 4 ]

=> Pair<1, Pair<2, Pair<3,4>>
```

So on the highest level I iterate through each element and convert all iterations to a union with `[keyof X & '${bigint}']`.

```
{
  [I in keyof X & `${bigint}`]: /* ... */
}[keyof X & `${bigint}`]
```

I then convert the index to the corresponding number and also skip the first iteration since we only need to cut the array `n - 1` times.

```
I extends keyof Indizes 
  ? Indizes[I] extends 0
    ? never
    : /* ... */
  : never
```

And last of all I create both sub-arrays with `Slice` and create a `Pair` of both sub-arrays by calling `_Catalan` with them.

```
Pair<_Catalan<Slice<X, 0, Indizes[I]>>, _Catalan<Slice<X, Indizes[I], X["length"]>>>
```

### Result

The end result looks like this:

```
type _Catalan<X extends unknown[]> = X["length"] extends 1 
  ? X[0]
  : X["length"] extends 2 
    ? Pair<X[0], X[1]>
    : {
        [I in keyof X & `${bigint}`]: I extends keyof Indizes 
          ? Indizes[I] extends 0
            ? never
            : Indizes[I] extends number 
              ? Pair<_Catalan<Slice<X, 0, Indizes[I]>>, _Catalan<Slice<X, Indizes[I], X["length"]>>>
              : never
          : never
    }[keyof X & `${bigint}`]

type Catalan<X, XS extends unknown[]> = _Catalan<[X, ...XS]>
```

Usage:

```
class Pair<A, B> {
    constructor(public fst: A, public snd: B) {}
}

type _Catalan<X extends unknown[]> = X["length"] extends 1 
  ? X[0]
  : X["length"] extends 2 
    ? Pair<X[0], X[1]>
    : {
        [I in keyof X & `${bigint}`]: I extends keyof Indizes 
          ? Indizes[I] extends 0
            ? never
            : Indizes[I] extends number 
              ? Pair<_Catalan<Slice<X, 0, Indizes[I]>>, _Catalan<Slice<X, Indizes[I], X["length"]>>>
              : never
          : never
    }[keyof X & `${bigint}`]

type Catalan<X, XS extends unknown[]> = _Catalan<[X, ...XS]>

type C0 = Catalan<1, []>; // 1

type C1 = Catalan<1, [2]>; // Pair<1, 2>

type C2 = Catalan<1, [2, 3]>; // Pair<1, Pair<2, 3>> | Pair<Pair<1, 2>, 3>

type C3 = Catalan<1, [2, 3, 4]>; /* Pair<1, Pair<2, Pair<3, 4>>> |
                                  * Pair<1, Pair<Pair<2, 3>, 4>> |
                                  * Pair<Pair<1, 2>, Pair<3, 4>> |
                                  * Pair<Pair<1, Pair<2, 3>>, 4> |
                                  * Pair<Pair<Pair<1, 2>, 3>, 4>
                                  */
```

If you hover over the type `C3`, you will notice that it looks different from what you specified. There are only `3` top-level unions and each member will have unions inside the `Pair`s.

```
Pair<1, Pair<2, Pair<3, 4>> | Pair<Pair<2, 3>, 4>>
//instead of 
Pair<1, Pair<2, Pair<3, 4>>> | Pair<1, Pair<Pair<2, 3>, 4>>
```

But this is purely a visual thing and they should functionally not be different.

Some tests to validate the result:

```
type Test1 = Pair<1, Pair<2, Pair<3, 4>>> extends C3 ? true : false
type Test2 = Pair<1, Pair<Pair<2, 3>, 4>> extends C3 ? true : false
type Test3 = Pair<Pair<1, 2>, Pair<3, 4>> extends C3 ? true : false
type Test4 = Pair<Pair<1, Pair<2, 3>>, 4> extends C3 ? true : false
type Test5 = Pair<Pair<Pair<1, 2>, 3>, 4> extends C3 ? true : false
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBAggIwM4HsA2BXEUA8AVGKAD2wDsATJGJEAJwEtSBzGAHxlIwFsEpa2YCek0YgAfDAC8MAsTKVqdRk2AwYAfhmESUClQAGAWgAkAb0YAzPjABKAX32q1G207UAuGU8+JUmbDj6ZngOYgDcwKCQsPRIAHJQTACGIPQAbriyOnoc3Ly0EtJBpiH62vIGJuakVvwA+g4udBiwnhZJaEhQEVHQMADKaPQAxlAAMlAWIDhOcLT8croKSaRgANoAugA0TgCSFMTlS1ScPHw7anhJ9GhHOSvrG1Iwm8CFMtdoawBEaLpMIAAFt8noscvtyMQnJo1lcblt4PMNt5EQtsgo1pZrAAJKBJcgIgB0xKx-BsUBoyLUmkGI3Gk2m5JoCIhxARa2JhLhaARuPxGzEKNhn3ZGw2PXAfVpoxswkB01m8zuy1WmwuMFZRGVVBoDGY6u52pgD02z1e72K3J+f2YQJBjTBCk10Jec1oCO5VJgngwpAA1qQUAB3UhGt1rAAMXphao+Ny9PiVjqoHJJNWsTJACNJMDGSUpLulUFlTHlOEzLIORHZeeZME5nsFHhesc9EuiAyGo01MzUbqNJu2eyrRtO+Tez1iCWSqQyOE1EmTMHanSgha79KmODdlchRCb3s7dJLZZ38GQ6CwuAX4UiktgRd7qIHqqHan6ICStBAo7y1mkEbqgAohQv5nPw0jhr8-x2si7xFj2CFVtu8wIiB5BiJG2xHt2yFnh+X7iFh1owcCAprAAjOKd4dhC9AAF4UmagEwBRCIAEwIgAzAiAAsCIAKwIgAbAiADsCIABwIgAnAiFEsRRbGsZxrE8ax-GsUJrGiaxEmsdJrFyTA7FRpEwxoPmVAAArXLQ24IgAQhIphuDAwwoKQuoYMMIAoLQAAUEAYAgXbLjQPgIsFoUjNQFCeI5ACUMCmHYwBpb0sB1AAwikHQrDgAAaRq+gGwakJs7yFSRtpkUaFEwC61Vmc21XQbVIJGuxjXOC4tn0PZzXYdVVEHs2rm9b1ay7DAjAwH6UBgCgFgwMVABkMDFEIIikCADgbJ4M1LgtS0rXRjFUG5k0uOdFLTaC6JUBGV3XS4pBQBktAvddh0UAxd27A9FS5OBPWvddmj9fZOV5ZZpA4I+hUIixt1IPdYhiAiMOfnDCMbkVu7-WjgMIm1NoAmRGNjeDzieO9n3fbTHAfXwbl2GsJ3LatMAbVtwiiPtNF9LlOMFUjq39CV-qBiGlXPNj+Xw2s4ucoV-QCkLsDZRGzwi4rODKZVYQwAA9CbrGazA2UNdIeu44b7ECsbZswFDBscYKmVW91tuwwVDvcU7pvm27ylu6pXEYwIbuhx73Ge-eVtcbrfvwwHMDqbxQcmwAVK7dnu-nA04KpbuZ1TbCMzT1evXnsdF-Z4fx3xUesFXNcd2odcF-X7GYw3ODlxIbed6PtcD-XTcZxjLeV2P8-ON3xcxwXyl983MC8dTC+dznJuW3gFIgDbA9hwXpcF0Pi6PUnTS0C0h4rl0XuHzQPunwiK-FxH-db9fwPZWTpoZorRlwdGfonV+IBk7SC-vZNe-cy4t3-scW+wD76gKfmuSBR9eLPDgYXKekdf4oJyIAu+D82jgOwR2KBAl8E90YcXBBG8t5GnIegyhYDVzACAA)

Comment: I think it is different. `Map<1, Map<2, 3> | Map<3, 4>>` is different from `Map<1, Map<2, 3>> | Map<1, Map<3, 4>>`. Interesting solution anyhow. What troubles me is the speed at which this type is evaluated. It's really slow and when I change something it takes a minute for the language server to re-compute types. I think we can do better.

Comment: A fix for the doubt I mentioned would be to use distributive conditional types like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NBkLVm). However, it's still pretty slow... I don't think this is viable in an environment with a lot more going on. Also, I would not suggest attempting inputs larger than 6, as the 6th catalan number is already 42 lol

Comment: Hi @catgirlkelly. How is `Map<1, Map<2, 3> | Map<3, 4>>` different from `Map<1, Map<2, 3>> | Map<1, Map<3, 4>>` ?

Comment: That's my bad. If the key (`1`) was something more general (like `number`), then it would be different. But here the key (and `fst`) is `1`, so there is actually no difference.

Comment: I would love to see a solution without `Splice`. Maybe this would have better performance

Comment: You can try a simple optimization: partition `xs` into `xs.slice(0, i)` and `xs.slice(i + 1)` all in one type, instead of doing two separate slice computations.

Comment: [And here it is.](https://tsplay.dev/mp9azW) I believe it is a faster solution using the above idea. Partitioning `XS` instead of slicing it separately. And the `Partition` type itself is also particularly fast. I've also written a `Show` type that does what the original JS `show` function does so you can verify that it works. TypeScript does not want to expand `CatalanLoop` in the tooltips :p

Comment: really nice! What is up with the `& '${bigint}'` thing?

Comment: `keyof [1, 2, 3]` => `number | "0" | "1" | "2" | "at" | "..."`. So we use `& '${bigint}'` to get only `"0" | "1" | "2"`. You could also use `number` but I like to use `bigint` because it only allows integers.